# Spring Data JPA, fetch parent entity and child entities with condition

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin

In a Spring Boot project with Data JPA I have an Entity Device which has a @OneToMany relationship with Entity Data as shown in the code below. The Data entity have timestamp attribute value.

I want to fetch all the Devices, each with its Data, but the Data entities only between specific timestamps.

```kotlin
@Entity
class DeviceDAO(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false) val id: String,
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true)
    val data: List<Data>,

    // more attributes 
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
class Data(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false) val id: Long? = null,
    @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "id") val device: DeviceDAO,
    val timestamp: Instant,

    // more attributes 
)
```

I have tried with a @Query annotated method in the Device repository

```kotlin
@Repository
interface DeviceRepository : JpaRepository<DeviceDAO, String> {

    @Query("select d from DeviceDAO d join fetch d.data da where da.timestamp between :startTimestamp and :endTimestamp")
    fun findDataToProcess(
        @Param("startTimestamp") startTimestamp: Instant,
        @Param("endTimestamp") endTimestamp: Instant
    ): List<DeviceDAO>
}
```

But the HQL [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) comment about the join fetch

> A fetch join does not usually need to assign an alias, because the associated objects should not be used in the where clause (or any other clause).

So I am guessing this is not recommended.

Is there another way to fetch the Devices and its Data the way I've described? Or what is the reason HQL docs say that?